# Property files with Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring (maven) project in which I am using property file. This property file contains UI labels and messages. 
In source code property file location is src/main/resources/message/ApplicationResources.properties
Output of this project is WAR file. Location of the property file inside war is WEB-INF/classes/message/ApplicationResources.properties

I am trying to use this property file like below

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <value>classpath*:message/ApplicationResources</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
        <value>classpath*:message/ApplicationResources</value>
</property> 
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

But every time I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [message/ApplicationResources] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
```

I did lot of google and tried almost all the options but nothing worked for me. With few options

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: NoNo message found under code 'label.meetingDescription' for locale 'en_US'
```

Comment: You make a mistake, it should be:
<value>classpath*:message/ApplicationMessages</value>

Comment: Edited my question. The only way I am able to get it working, move property file under src/main/resources/ and change configuration to <value>classpath:ApplicationResources</value>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution. Below configurations worked for me.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:message/ApplicationResources.properties"/>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="WEB-INF/classes/message/ApplicationResources"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You should not need the <context:property-placeholder if you put in your basenames property value="classpath:..." as i pointed in mi answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your configuration to:

```
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath*:message/ApplicationMessages.properties</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

or

```
<property name="location">
       <value>classpath*:message/ApplicationMessages.properties</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This is not working. I am still getting javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: NoNo message found under code 'label.meetingDescription' for locale 'en_US'

Comment: for that, can you see if label.meetingDescription exists in ApplicationMessages.properties. Please check the spelling carefully.

Comment: The only way I am able to get it working, move property file under src/main/resources/ and change configuration to <value>classpath:ApplicationResources</value>

Comment: Yes label.meetingDescription exists in ApplicationMessages.properties

Answer (score 0):

I've faced some similar problems and finally get it to work pointing to the resources file name, not specifying a directory. My example uses several files but it's almost the same:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:applicationMessages,classpath:ValidationMessages"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ApplicationMessage.properties is in src/main/resources/message you have to use

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basenames">
       <value>classpath*:/message/ApplicationResources</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

(be careful of /message/).

If you don't use / at the beginning of the classpath it 's referering to current folder. With / it's the root folder of the classpath (aka src/main/resources)